# Can X-Ray for ArcCatalog handle attribute indexes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

I've been using the excellent ArcCatalog [X-Ray](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ea218ff575f4a5195e01a2cae03a0ae) for working with designing a geodatabase.

Is there a way to create attribute indexes in X-Ray?  The geodatabase XML schema does contain an  element, but I can't find any mechanism or guidance if X-Ray can handle indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the code of X-Ray, it seems they use a simplified version of the geodatabase schema in the XML.  The  element is missing, so at the moment, there is no support for indexes that I can see.